# How display all top 1 product on collection list one one page?

Tags: collections, shopify

I'm trying to display all top 1 product on the collection on one page. but I know how to do that.

I share upload three screenshots I want them to display on one page. Any tips?

[image]

Comment: I think you need to utilize the concepts of meta fields to add and edit this content. you can custom code or use 3rd party APP to handle the meta fields across the Shopify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this.

1 way.  Start by creating a new collection with a condition, select `product type` is equal to `top 1`.  In the product you want to appear in that collection, add `top 1` to the type.

2. ```
   {% for collection in collections %}
    {% for product in collection.products %}
        {% if forloop.index == 1%}
        {% comment %}display product{% endcomment %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %} {% endfor %}
   ```

The above code will select first product on every collections in the shop.  To control which to appear as first, go to the collection and select the sort orders.

Comment: Hi @Charles C, it is working i just add some additional codes :) thank you